# Is there a website that will tell me the duration of a flight?

Tags: online-resources, flight-status

I wanted to look up the duration of my flight, but sadly I could only find arrival and departure time. This would mean that I would still have to look up time zones. Is there a website that can do this?

Comment: This isn't worth making a complete answer for, but please do note that most scheduled durations err on the side of being longer than needed. Many airlines exaggerate their flight times by about 10 minutes so they have better metrics, although none of them will admit that.

Comment: Which search engine were you using? In my search experience, all the search engines return the departure and arrival time **and** flight duration (e.g. Skyscanner, Google Flights, ITA Matrix, etc.) The airline companies usually show the flight duration as well.

Comment: don't you know the timezone of the place where you are going?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a specific flight in mind, with the flight number, you can use [FlightAware](http://flightaware.com/), which has pretty good global coverage for most airlines. The duration is shown on the right: actual duration for completed flights and scheduled duration for upcoming/in progress ones.

Answer (score 11):

[Hipmunk](https://www.hipmunk.com) gives you a nice graphical representation of flights and their duration.

[image]

Comment: "Mystery Airline"? "British"? Oh dear.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, I've not seen that before. It's a bit bizarre and not much of a mystery!

Comment: An explanation to the mystery airline: https://twitter.com/thehipmunk/status/177098567515774977

Comment: @tricasse Yeah, but there's no mystery in giving the exact departure and arrival! The only mystery is why it costs more than than buying it from BA